# Execute a python script whenever the viewport is changed

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view

I'd like to align a plane to the 3D-view. The idea is to have a number/ symbol that is always upright and readable no matter the viewing angle. while I can figure the alignment part out, I have no idea how to execute the script whenever the viewport is changed. The handlers don't have a redraw event.

Comment: Is it just for viewport visualization? If so, you can register a draw function to the 3DView class redraw handler with bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(); that will execute whenever a redraw is called. (check the 'operator modal draw' template, as it shows how it works)

Comment: Very promising. It's just a pity that most python examples are either made for people who just copy or for very experienced guys. The amount of comments in modal draw reflects that. So far I managed the script to fire indefinitely. By now it has counted to 5476. No idea how to remove it since I don't know how a handle is supposed to look. Blender Python is very easy in parts and terribly obscure in others unless you have studied programming.

Comment: the draw_handler_add() returns the handle to the draw function... to remove the function from the Editor, you just need to call draw_handler_remove() with the given handler.